# Create sidebar in yii framework

Tags: yii, sidebar

how to create dynamic sidebar in yii framework:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div id="content">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
</div><!-- content -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

look like:

```
<?php $this->beginContent('//layouts/main'); ?>
<div id="content">
    <?php echo $content; ?>
    <div id="sidebar">
        <?php echo $sidebar; ?>
    </div>
</div><!-- content -->
<?php $this->endContent(); ?>
```

Comment: We do this with a own widget in my company. So, create a widget with a run() method within a echo which display the html code. You can display your widget everywhere with $this->widget('...')

Comment: i code file run widget in folder themes/classic/views/layouts/file.php. how to render file.php in class widget?

Comment: Use Yii::setPathOfAlias() in your config file to create an alias pointing to your widget directory and use $this->widget('youralias.yourwidgetname');

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this answer is actual, but maybe somebody will help http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/127/dynamic-sidebar-using-cclipwidget/